# Springdoc OpenAPI displays class relationships under schemas and examples

Tags: spring-boot, spring-rest, spring-restdocs, springdoc, springdoc-openapi-ui

I am using springdoc-openapi for REST API documentation. I have two classes which has One to One relationship between them. After I create the API, When I use the API. It returns exactly the way it stored in the database, but the example values or schema shown in the docs display the complete relationship between them. I don't want to display the relationship between them instead display only the way it would get the response. The following image, the first highlighted one is the actual result and second one is the example value shown. The second one displays the relationship between Room and Check-in. How can I avoid this displaying??

[image]

Comment: You need to add `@JsonIgnore` on `checkin_id` in your parent entity

Comment: Adding the answer so that others will know you can accept the same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add `@JsonIgnore` on `checkin_id` in your parent entity.

`@JsonIgnore` Will not add the `checkin_id` in your sample and actual response.